# Analyzing logical form of ∀x∀yM(x, y)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have been going through Velleman's `How to prove` book and in one of their sample problems they have used `∀x∀yM(x, y)` for representing all married couples where

```
M(x,y): x and y are married to each to each other
```

But on deeper thought, I'm confused by this statement. Let the Universe of discourse be all peoples and let us substitute `x` as `Joey`. Now the statement will be like this:

```
∀yM(Joey, y)
```

which roughly translates to: for all people y, Joey is married to y.

But isn't that false because a person can't be married to everyone.

UPDATE: How actually Velleman uses it:

"All married couples have fights" is translated to

```
∀x∀y(M(x, y) → F(x, y)), where M(x, y) means “x and y are married to
each other” and F(x, y) means “x and y fight with each other.”
```

Comment: if you want $M$ to be an injective function symbol, then it´s false.

Comment: Are you missing a colon?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow where ?

Comment: Between $y$ and $M(x,y)$. Then it would read something along the lines of "for all x and y such that x is married to y."

Comment: Yes, it should read along the lines of what you have stated.

Comment: Read it as "All the Ys that are married to Joey" not "All Ys are married to Joey"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Velleman says what you claim he did, he is making a mistake. Or more likely, you misunderstood.

Expressions like $$\forall x. \exists y . \text{$y$ is the mother of $x$}$$ are *statements*; they are either true or false.  (This one happens to be true.)   They do not represent sets of any sort.

However, one can use the so-called *set-comprehension notation* to represent the set of things of which some statement is true.  The notation $\{x \mid P(x)\}$ represents the set of all things $x$ for which the statement $P(x)$ is true.  For example:

$$\{x \mid \text{Anne is the mother of $x$} \}$$ is the set that contains every person of whom Anne is the mother: it is the set of Anne's children, in other words.

Your example might be $$\{\langle x,y\rangle \mid \text{$x$ and $y$ are married}\}$$
which is the set of all pairs $\langle x, y\rangle$ where $x$ and $y$ are married.  One of the many pairs in this set is the pair $\langle \text{Queen Elizabeth II}, \text{Prince Philip}\rangle$. If Velleman claims that this set is represented by the expression $$\forall x\forall y. \text{$x$ and $y$ are married}$$ then he is wrong; if he said something else that you understood to mean this, then you misunderstood.  As you observed, $\forall x\forall y. \text{$x$ and $y$ are married}$ is a statement, not a set, and it happens to be false, since it asserts, among other things, that Michael Jackson is married to Julius Caesar.

Similarly, $$\forall y.\text{Joey is married to $y$}$$ asserts that Joey is married to everyone, which is false.  But $$\{y\mid \text{Joey is married to $y$}\}$$ represents the set of all people that are married to Joey.

---

You have updated the question to make clear that it concerns the statement $$\forall x\forall y . \text{$x$ is married to $y$} \to \text{$x$ fights with $y$}.\tag{$\star$}$$ This is a statement, intended to assert that  if $x$ and $y$ are married, then they fight with one another, or colloquially “all married couples fight".

It does *not* assert that everyone is married to everyone else, which would be $$\forall x  \forall y . \text{$x$ is married to $y$}.$$  It only asserts that  for any $x$ and $y$, *if* they are married *then* they fight.

Let's suppose this is actualy true, that all married couples *do* fight.  As you observe, we should be able to put in anything we want for $x$ and $y$ and obtain a true statement.  Let's take $x=\text{Michael Jackson}$ and $y=\text{Julius Caesar}$.  Then the statement asserts, for this example, that

$$\text{Michael Jackson is married to Julius Caesar} \to \text{Michael Jackson fights with Julius Caesar}.$$

That is, *if* Michael Jackson and Julius Caesar are married, *then* they fight.  This is an implication, and since the antecedent is false, the entire statement  is **true** whether or not they fight.  So even though $x$ and $y$ are not married in this case, the statement is true anyway.  (See the discussion of implication on page 43.)

Comment: I have updated the question to include how actually Velleman uses it.